# Manually uninstall software without package control

Tags: filesystem, uninstall, software-uninstall, arduino

On my Kubuntu <s>18.10</s> 19.04 system, I have a software installed (in this case: the Arduino IDE), which I would like to completely uninstall.

- I cannot remember how I installed it, but it does not show up in `dpkg --list` or the  software center and `apt-get purge` won't find it. I'm pretty sure it was installed without any package manager.
- I downloaded the current (newer than installed) version from the developer's website (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), which includes an `unistall.sh` script. But the only effect it seems to have is that the launcher shortcut (which is still there, for that matter) doesn't work anymore - the software can still be run from terminal (by simply typing `arduino`).

**What, generally, are the steps to take to manually uninstall software from my system?** I assume it's mainly deleting files, but how do I locate them all? Are there any databases I need to un-register the software from?

Comment: What is the output of `type -a arduino`? Also 18.10 reached its End of Life in July 2019, thus, off-topic here.

Comment: @Kulfy Output is `arduino ist /home/jmb/.local/share/umake/bin/arduino`. Sorry, I totally missed the EoL and will upgrade, but the question should apply regardless.

Comment: That implies you installed that using umake a.k.a. Ubuntu make. You can uninstall that by running `umake ide arduino --remove`

Comment: @Kulfy That results in an error: https://pastebin.com/RVacpiRc (it is still installed, and I can still start it)

Comment: What is the output of `locate arduino`?

Comment: @Kulfy it's almost 12,000 lines long. About 6000 of those begin with `/home/jmb/.local/share/umake/`. Removing those, personal files and icon packs, the rest is https://pastebin.com/HXX8Zmqk

Comment: Well I believe you can delete all these files if you don't want to keep Arduino IDE's configuration and data.

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: @guiverc Sorry about that, I didn't get the memo. I've upgraded now, but the question remains

Answer (score 0):

All your `sudo` commands are logged in `/var/log/auth.log` and it's `logrotate`d history. Find the commands you used to install it there.

Alternatively, you could install the `installwatch`, package, read the docs, and re-install the old package with `installwatch` keeping an eye on things.

2nd alternative- inspect (`tar tvf` or equivalent) the original (or re- downloaded original) archive.